# How to select specific lines and echo at the end in bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How can I take specific lines from pipeline and then echo them at the end. To show what I mean - I have few lines sent through pipeline and proccesing like this

```
#!bin/bash   
 while read line; do
 echo "$line"
done
```

I have this input

```
foo1 -> long
foo1 -> hell
foo1 -> fail
foo1
fast1 -> fine
fast1 -> good
fast1
```

I need to do this

```
foo1 -> long
foo1 -> hell
foo1 -> fail
fast1 -> fine
fast1 -> good
fast1
foo1
```

Just an example - there would be much longer input to process

Comment: You would need to be able to store off the lines you don't like into an array or something, then loop through that structure at the end.  This might be a useful starting point: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use BASH array to store certain lines in array to be printed later:

```
lines=()
while read line; do
 if [[ $someCondition ]]; then
   lines+=("$line")
 else
   echo "$line"
 fi
done

# print array now:
printf "%s\n" "${lines[@]}"
```

Comment: The problem with this is, that after done it closes the pipeline so the array - lines - doesnt exist anymore - its empty

Comment: That depends if you're using a pipe in while loop and processing it in a sub shell. You can avoid sub shell creation using process substitution.

Comment: Oh yeah, now its working. One more question though. Does the process substitution - uniq -u >tmp - create something similar like file? Because I mustn create any file. Thank you very much.

Comment: You can avoid creating file by using `done < <($cmd)` in for loop.